# Change NaN values in one data frame to elements with the same coordinates in a different data frame

Tags: r

Is there a way to change an `NaN` value from one dataframe, to the value with the same coordinates in another dataframe?

For example:

I have two data frames with the same dimensions:

`E
      Y9  Y10  Y11  Y12 Y13  Y14 Y15
Eel 2.64 2.97 2.95 2.95   3 2.75 NaN`

and

`AO
             Y9  Y10  Y11  Y12  Y13 Y14 Y15
All Others 2.41 2.24 2.96 2.98 3.28   3   3`

I am trying to replace all values of `NaN` in dataframe `E` with the element in `AO` with matching coordinates, so [,7].

I have tried

`E[E==NaN]<-AO[,7]`

Which doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't return an error, but `E` still contains NaN.  Also, this code doesn't tell R to replace NaN with the value contained in the same coordinates of `AO` without manually specifying [,7].

Comment: Check `?NaN`. You should not check equality to `NaN`. Instead try using `is.nan` with apply.

Comment: `bm=is.nan(as.matrix(E)); E[bm] <- A0[bm]`

Comment: @MaratTalipov, it worked!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two data frames with the same dimension, you can try this

```
E[is.na(E)] <- A[is.na(E)]
```